# Spring MVC method not returning JSON string to jQuery ajax call - Part II

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

Java 8 / Spring 4 MVC webapp / Maven / jQuery 3.3.1

So I crafted a Spring MVC webapp whose index.jsp uses an ajax call. Note that I've swapped out the obsolete jQuery success and error for the modern done and fail

--- index.jsp snippet ----

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var arrayData, objectData;
  arrayData = this.serializeArray();
  objectData = {};

  $.each(arrayData, function() {
    var value;

    if (this.value != null) {
      value = this.value;
    } else {
      value = '';
    }

    if (objectData[this.name] != null) {
      if (!objectData[this.name].push) {
        objectData[this.name] = [objectData[this.name]];
      }

      objectData[this.name].push(value);
    } else {
      objectData[this.name] = value;
    }
  });

  return objectData;
};

function popupRuleDeck_update_submit() {
    var formJsonObj = $('#form_popupRuleDeck_update').serializeObject();
    var formJsonStr = JSON.stringify( formJsonObj);
    $.ajax({
      url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ruleDeck_update',
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: formJsonStr
    }).done( function(response, message, xhr) {
        console.log("done entered")
        console.dir( response);
        var selectedRow = $('#ruleDeckTable > tbody > tr.selected')
        var selectedData = selectedRow.data();
        console.log( "selectedRowData: " + selectedRowData);
        console.log( "response.data: " + response.data() );
        $('#ruleDeckTable').row( selectedRow).data( response).draw();
        console.log("done exited")
    }).fail( function( xhr, status, response) {
        console.dir( "failed status:" + status);
        console.dir( "failed response:" + response);
        var returnedStr = JSON.stringify( response);
        $.each( response, function( key, val) {
            console.log("---" + key + ":" + val);
        });
        console.dir( "failed returnedStr:" + returnedStr);
        alert( "ruleDeck insert/update error: " + response)
      return false;
    });
}
```

to a method in my controller which is annotated with @Controller  **NOT** @RestController

```
@RequestMapping( value="/ruleDeck_update", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody RuleDeck ruleDeckUpdateUpdate( @RequestBody RuleDeck formRuleDeck)
{
    logger.info("entering ruleDeckUpdateUpdate");

    RuleDeck ruleDeck = null;

    try {
        ruleDeck = tryThisService.findOneRuleDeck( formRuleDeck.getId());
        ruleDeck.setRuleDeckId( formRuleDeck.getRuleDeckId());
        ruleDeck.setRevision( formRuleDeck.getRevision());
        ruleDeck.setName( formRuleDeck.getName());
        ruleDeck.setDeckType( formRuleDeck.getDeckType());
        ruleDeck.setFileLocation( formRuleDeck.getFileLocation());
        ruleDeck = tryThisService.updateOneRuleDeck( ruleDeck);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ruleDeck.setName( "JPE:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        ruleDeck.setName( "Exception:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info("exiting  ruleDeckUpdateUpdate");
    return ruleDeck;  //should be implicitly converted into json format and sent back to the request.
}
```

As before, the ajax call sends the JSON to the method, which does find and update an existing object, which gets saved in the database, so far so good. The method executes without errors. But now the .fail() gets called and I see the following in the browser console

```
failed status: error
failed response:
failed returnedStr:
```

This would all seem to indicate the "return ruleDeck" statement at the end of my java method is in fact returning nothing, or maybe an empty string. 
I'm stumped. I'd expect response to be a JSON object according to posts like [here](http://javaonlineguide.net/2015/07/spring-4-mvc-restful-webservice-example-without-maven.html)

Or maybe a better way to go is to return a ResponseEntity( ruleDeck, HttpStatus.OK)  . But then how would I read that in back in browser-land?

Help Please!

TIA,

code_warrior

Comment: Have you ever been debugging your controller? It should be very simple.

Comment: If by debugging you mean does the form data come over from the browser and implicitly converted to an RuleDeck object which I then use to build up a new RuleDeck object and update the database and verify the row in the underlying table does indeed have one or more values changed and committed, then Yes I think I have debugged the controller method and believe that is now where the problem lies. But I am open to constructive suggestions, thx for replying